# How to push a div inside this div structure?

Tags: html

I have tried many things but I still haven't found a decent solution.

**Whilst desiging a webpage, I'm using this lay-out (lay-out using different full length colored stripes in the background as sections):**

```
<body>
<div id="wrap_banner" class="bg_banner">
<div id="wrapcentering_banner">
  <p>Here comes banner</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="wrap_middle" class="bg_middle">
<div id="wrapcentering_middle">
  <p>text</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="wrap_footer" class="bg_footer">
<div id="wrapcentering_footer">
    <table width="879" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td class="text_webmade">
    <p>
    Company</p></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS contains following:**

```
#wrap_banner, #wrap_middle, #wrap_footer {
position: relative;
height: auto;
}

#wrapcentering_footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -500px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}

#wrapcentering_middle{
        position: relative;
        width: 1000px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -500px;
        height: auto;
        top: 0px;
    }


#wrapcentering_banner {
        position: relative;
        width: 1000px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -500px;
        height: 200px;
        top: 0px;
    }

.bg_middle, .bg_footer, .bg_banner {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
      background-color:#FFF
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

Any div I'm putting in the wrapcentering_banner containing an automatic height is NOT pushing the footer div down. Depending on the Z-index, it's putting the content either behind the footer div er on top of the footer div, but it never pushes the div's.

I tried to put some relative divs in one container div ( inside the wrapcentering div ) using automatic heights and float lefts, but still nothing is pushing the divs down. Offcourse absolute divs are not working either.

The only solution I have to get the content shown is giving the wrapcentering div a specific height and making sure the contents is made for that height. Or I have to use a table in wrapcentering div. Tables pushes the footer divs down.

Since I'm not a big fan of tables, is there a way to push these divs down?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving automatic heights and floats to the wrapcentering_banner div and clearing the float for the footer div. This will make sure the footer div does not float along with the upper divs and will position it below the other divs.