# DIVs inside DIV height issue

Tags: css, html

**Problem**

I'm trying to make something similar to the image below, where black is the body with `id="library"`, grey div `id="body"` (is not visible due to lack of margins for inner divs), light blue div `id="sideBar"`, red div `id="content"`, blue div `id="navBar"` and green div `id="contentWindow"`.

**Image:**

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wplyfqJ.png?1]

I'm having trouble containing the green div inside the red div (the greens parent). Basically I would like to configure only the greens margins with respect to the red div and not have to set the height explicitly. This is my implementation:

http://jsfiddle.net/efntL/

I would like all divs to adjust to the screen width and height so that everything is visible at all times (down to small browser windows).

I've looked at the following links but they haven't provided anything useful:

[Resizable DIV inside DIV 100% height with margin around not working well! Some help please?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263982/resizable-div-inside-div-100-height-with-margin-around-not-working-well-some-h)

[How to push a div inside this div structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892338/how-to-push-a-div-inside-this-div-structure)

[Parent div expand with children Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181943/parent-div-expand-with-children-div)

**The code can be seen in the fiddle above but I've also included it here:**

```css
body.library,
html {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 none;
}

div#body {
  /*display:block;*/
  background: #E6E6E6;
  max-width: 400px;
  display: block;
  height: 90%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

div#sidebar {
  /*display:block;
    position:relative;*/
  background: #94DBFF;
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
}

div#content {
  /*display:block;
    position:relative;*/
  background: #FF0000;
  min-width: 70px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

div#contentWindow {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 80px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

div#navBar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body class="library">
  <div id=body>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <p>Hej</p>
      <p>Hej</p>
      <p>Hej</p>
      <p>Hej</p>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      <div id="navBar">
        <p>Hey</p>
      </div>

      <div id="contentWindow">
        <p>Hej</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your navBar has a fixed height then this might work for you:

```
body.library, html {
    background:black;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    border: 0 none;
}

div#body {
     /*display:block;*/
    background:#E6E6E6;
    max-width:400px;
    display:block;
    height:90%;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;  
}

div#sidebar{
    /*display:block;
    position:relative;*/
    background:#94DBFF;
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:100%;    
}

div#content{
    display:block;
    position:relative; //position relative to contain the absolutely positioned element
    background:#FF0000; 
    min-width:70px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    height:100%;
}

div#contentWindow{
    display: block;
    position:absolute; //set the position to absolute
    height:auto;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-top:50px; //increase margin top to have the navBar visible
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    background-color: green;
}

div#navBar {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Check out the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/taneleero/8TQKW/

Comment: Thank you! But I'm curious, the green div seems to be slightly above the navbar (see http://jsfiddle.net/8TQKW/1/), is it possible to fix that so that the margins for the green div is relative to the area below the white div? And is it possible to have a navbar with adjusting height?

Comment: Besides this solution the only way I can think of achieving this is to use either javascript or tables (and it hurts to say this). I would go with javascript personally. Get the difference of the #content and #navbar heights and apply it to #contentWindow. This would have to happen on load and resize.

Answer (score 1):

**Html Part:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inside-left"></div>
    <div id="inside-right">
        <div id="top"></div>
        <div id="bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Css Part:**

```
#wrapper {    
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 7%;
}
#inside-left {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: cyan;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 400px;
}
#inside-right {
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: red;
    width: 70%;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;    
    height: 400px;
}
#inside-right #top {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 70%;
    width: 100%;
}
#inside-right #bottom {
    margin-top: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: green;
    height: 28%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Look in my example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efntL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completely resizable solution.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#library {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#library #body {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 3% 5%;
}
#library #body #sidebar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: #8eeeff;
  margin: 2%;
}
#library #body #content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 2%;
}
#library #body #content #navbar {
  width: 90%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 3% 5%;
}
#library #body #content #contentwindow {
  width: 90%;
  height: 70%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 3% 5%;
}
```

markup

```
<body id="library">


        <div id="body">

            <div id="sidebar"></div>

            <div id="content">

                <div id="navbar"></div>

                <div id="contentwindow"></div>

            </div>

        </div>


</body>
```